# Error when trying to retrieve json data from h2 database

Tags: scala, h2, scalikejdbc

I have the following table definition

```
create table samples (
   channel text,
   eventType text,
   data json NOT NULL
);
```

I have also tried defining the `data` column as `clob`,`text`,`java_object`,`varchar`,`other`.
I am using the following API to insert data in h2:

```
def insert(sample: Sample): Unit = DB localTx { implicit session =>
    val propertiesJson = new PGobject()
    propertiesJson.setType("json")
    propertiesJson.setValue(sample.properties.toJson.toString)
    sql"""
         insert into samples
         (channel,eventType,data) values (${sample.channel}, ${sample.eventType},$propertiesJson )
    """.update().apply()

}
```

and this one to retrieve data

```
  def find(channel: String): List[Sample] = DB readOnly { implicit session =>
    sql"""
     select * from samples where channel = $channel
     """.map(rs => {

     Sample(
       channel = rs.string("channel"),
       properties = rs.string("data").parseJson.convertTo[Map[String, String]],
       eventType = rs.string("eventType")
     )
    }
    ).list().apply()
   }
```

I'm using implicit conversions using `spray` and the `scalikejdbc` driver.

There are the different errors I am getting depending on the data type of the `data` column.

- For `CLOB`,`VARCHAR`,`TEXT` and `JAVA_OBJECT`: I can insert data in h2 but when trying to retrieve I get

  ```
  spray.json.JsonParser$ParsingException: Unexpected character 'a' at input index 0 (line 1, position 1), expected JSON Value: aced00057372001c6f72672e706f737467726573716c2e7574696c2e50476f626a656374f903de2682bdcb3b0200024c0004747970657400124c6a6176612f6c616e672f537472696e673b4c000576616c756571007e000178707400046a736f6e74001f7b2270726f7041223a2276616c41222c2270726f7042223a2276616c42227d
  ```
- For `JSON`. I cannot even insert data into h2. I'm getting

  ```
  Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLDataException: Data conversion error converting "OTHER to JSON" [22018-200]
  at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:457)
  at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:429)
  ... 114 more
  ```

When using `JSON` I also tried this `format json` directive proposed [here](http://www.h2database.com/html/datatypes.html#json_type)

> See also json literal grammar. Mapped to byte[]. To set a JSON value
> with java.lang.String in a PreparedStatement use a FORMAT JSON data
> format (INSERT INTO TEST(ID, DATA) VALUES (?, ? FORMAT JSON)). Without
> the data format VARCHAR values are converted to a JSON string values.

but the error was still the same.

So any ideas? How can I successfully insert and retrieve JSON data from an h2 database? Is there anything wrong with my approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Scala, but you definitely can't use `PGobject` with H2, this class is specific to PgJDBC. To pass a JSON value to H2, you need to use a plain byte array (`byte[]` in Java, `Array[Byte]` in Scala); the passed array should contain JSON text in UTF-8, UTF-16, or UTF-32 encoding. You can also use a `java.lang.String` if you wish, but it will require `FORMAT JSON` clause in SQL after parameter.

To read a JSON value from H2 it would be better to use `ResultSet.getBytes(…)` in Java/JDBC and `WrappedResultSet.bytes(…)` in ScalikeJDBC, it will return byte array with JSON text in UTF-8 encoding. Currently you're using a `string(…)` method, it should work too at least with H2 1.4.200, but such behavior is not documented and may be changed in the future releases.

These suggestions are for builtin JSON data type of H2.